# Cannot draw text to custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having an issue using the canvas.drawText() method.

I have a custom view, as follows:

```
public class PagerIndicator extends View
{
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {       
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(10);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    canvas.drawText("TEST", 0, 0, paint);
}
```

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ysi.crm.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/swipe_page_indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The drawPaint() method **is** working, I can see the gray paint when I test. However, canvas.drawText() is not drawing. I see no text on top of the gray.

I've beat this thing to death, I could find no one else who's had this problem, much less a solution. I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this before. The coordinate that you set it to draw with is not the top left coordinate of the text. It is the bottom left coordinate of the text.

Because of this, your text is probably being drawn above the top of your view.

Comment: That was it! I can't believe I didn't catch it. Seems intentionally confusing to use the bottom left as the origin, thanks Android. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class PagerIndicator extends View
{
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {       
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint1);

    Paint paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint2.setTextSize(10);
    paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    canvas.drawText("TEST", 0, 0, paint2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately this was something I tried earlier to no avail. I just tried again to be sure and I'm still not seeing text.

Comment: Have you tried to change the position  0,0 to another one? I remember having problems because the text wasn't exactly at that position.
I also recomend you to set Size to a big one.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
canvas.drawText("TEST", 0, 0, paint2);
```

to:

```
canvas.drawText("TEST", 100, 100, paint2);
```